# Getting pod associated with job

Tags: kubernetes

How do I get the pod associated with a job via the Kubernetes REST API? I cannot figure out how the two are related/linked other than by similar (but not the same) generated names.

Comment: Does the `describe` endpoint show you information about the pods?

Answer (score 2):

You can send a LIST request for pods, with [ListOptions.LabelSelector](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/d16981aedf33f88b7434bd3bdbcc2e1f940aecd0/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L355) set to the [selector of the Job](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/dcce3486da333605791aa8b98536ca01893194d6/batch/v1/types.go#L99).

If you are not using the [go client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) for kubernetes, you need to spell the LabelSelector as a query parameter, e.g., `https://<host_address>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=component%3Dspark-master`